# Execute jar file on start up

Tags: java, jar

I'm making a little program in Java that I want to use everytime the computer starts, I know how to manually put the jar in the list of programs to make it execute during start up but i wonder if there's a way of doing manually, changing the register files or something like that, or maybe there's already a library that helps you to do this?

I don't want to touch the register if I can, any recomendations on what to use?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not very precise... First, this is operating system specific - may I assume Windows? If so, there are many ways to make a (any) program run at startup - which one is the one you know already? Link in any of the `startup` folders? Finally: *"every time the computer starts"* - really OS startup - or rather, when a specific user (you) logs in?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-add-a-program-to-startup/91d18255-659e-4796-87f6-5e6c814c7d50?auth=1

Comment: Sorry that i wasn't clear enought,  I wanted it to happen on Windows, I want to know if there's a way of just clicking the jar file and automaticaly include it in one of the startup folders.

Comment: Windows does not offer such an option for any other executable either. You will have to go the classic way: Create some link and move it to the start up folder by hand -- *unless* you are willing to implement this link creation from within your java application or use some installer for (e. g. [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-apps-for-creating-installation-packages/) some examples).